# SQL Stored Procedure set variables using SELECT

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, select

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 with multiple variables and I want to set the values of these variables using a select statement. All three variables come from a same table and there should be a way to set them using one select statement instead of the way I currently have as shown below. Please help me to figure it out.

```
DECLARE @currentTerm nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @termID int

DECLARE @endDate datetime

SET @currentTerm =
(
    Select CurrentTerm from table1 where IsCurrent = 1
)

SET @termID =
(
    Select TermID from table1 where IsCurrent = 1
)

SET @endDate =
(
    Select EndDate from table1 where IsCurrent = 1
)
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
select @currentTerm = CurrentTerm, @termID = TermID, @endDate = EndDate
    from table1
    where IsCurrent = 1
```

Comment: I have been writing the similar statements. Comparing my statement with this one, I have been receiving @currentTerm = CurrentTerm as a variable and the value returned is NULL. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, it always returns null

Answer (score 15):

One advantage your current approach does have is that it will raise an error if multiple rows are returned by the predicate. To reproduce that you can use.

```
SELECT @currentTerm = currentterm,
       @termID = termid,
       @endDate = enddate
FROM   table1
WHERE  iscurrent = 1

IF( @@ROWCOUNT <> 1 )
  BEGIN
      RAISERROR ('Unexpected number of matching rows',
                 16,
                 1)

      RETURN
  END
```